# inline validator function not working for model in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating offer for products thats why I have implemented several model at create function in controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Offer();
    $wmodel = new Wmoffer();
    $pmodel = new Product();
    $ummodel = new Unitofmeasurement();
    $qvmodel = new OfferingValue();
    $blmodel = new OfferLocation();

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    // code manipulation
   }else{
       return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'wmodel' => $wmodel,
            'pmodel' => $pmodel,
            'qvmodel' => $qvmodel,
            'blmodel' => $blmodel,
            'ummodel' => $ummodel
        ]); 
   }
```

all of my model extends by ActiveRecord aspect `Wmoffer()` this model looks like as below

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

class Wmoffer extends Model
{
   public $bIsProductOrService;
   public $iCatalogueID;
   public $imageProduct;
   public $nHasCurrencyValue;
   public $nHasCurrencyValueMRP;
   public $BusinesslocationIds;


   public function rules() 
   { 
     // validation rules
```

Now i need to implement inline validator for start,end date comparison [Start Date should be greater than End Date ]

i have tried [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) but this is not working i know something is missing which causes this 
Any suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: what is not working ? like any error ? or simply validation is not done ?

Comment: in model `Wmoffer()` rules function
 `['nHasCurrencyValue', 'customValidator', 'params' => ['extraFields' => 'nHasCurrencyValueMRP']],` 
 `public function customValidator($attribute, $params) {
        if($this->nHasCurrencyValue > $this->{$params['extraFields']}){
            $this->addError('nHasCurrencyValue', 'Max Error');
        }
    }`
 I have implemented this but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$model->errors` value after calling `$model->validate()` to look for validation errors.

Your *dates* validator method can be something like:

```
public function validateDates($attribute, $params) {
    if ($this->hasErrors()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->dateStart > $this->dateEnd)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Start date can not be greater than end date');
    }
}
```

**Add it to `rules()` in your backend models.**

Comment: @stig-js i have added this but its not working in my case :(